# Hints on designing a scheme for page view logs using Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I'm trying to design a scheme for event logs, which record page view flow on webpages, using [Neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org).

I'm interested in finding page view flows to a certain collection of pages (URLs). I'm thinking defining `nodes` as page view events and important `properties` include user id, timestamp, etc. The only relationship between `nodes` is `visit`.

I'm completely new to Neo4j. So is this design reasonable?

Comment: Makes sense. I would probably model the user as a node too, which is connected to the view event.

Answer (score 0):

If the properties are recurring, I would model them as nodes, too. You could even look at things like http://datablend.be/?p=1516 for inspiration.

Comment: Please update your answer with a new link as the existing one is currently unavailable.